# limit superior of sequences in real line

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$. Is the limit superior of $(a_{n_k})$ less than or equal to the limit superior of $(a_n)$ for any subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$?

Comment: Any bounded sub-sequences converges to the same limit of the sequence.

(assuming the original sequence converges).

Comment: @elbarto But one does not want to assume this.

Answer (score 3):

Two observations.

1. The limit superior of a sequence is the same as the limit superior of the set of numbers in the sequence. The set of numbers in a subsequence is a subset of the set of numbers in the original sequence.
2. In general, if $A$ and $B$ are sets with $A\subseteq B$ then
   $$
   \limsup A\leq\limsup B.
   $$
   This is because every upper bound for $B$ is an upper bound for $A$, but there could be an upper bound for $A$ that is not an upper bound for $B$ since $A$ can be missing large elements of $B$.

Do these help?

Answer (score 0):

$\limsup a_n$ is the largest subsequential limit of $a_n.$ Every subsequence of $a_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $a_n,$ hence no subsequential limit of $a_{n_k}$ can be larger than the largest subsequential limit of $a_n.$ Therefore $\limsup a_{n_k} \le \limsup a_n.$